# Notetaking application that is programmer friendly

Tags: windows, linux, software-development, note-taking, offline

I'm having trouble finding a notetaking application for Windows(and hopefully Linux) that handles code snippets well.

It can sync online, but I would prefer it to have good offline functionality. I would like to be able to store notebooks in various folders, by project, similar to how you would store .txt or .docx files.

I would choose Evernote, but that has never been great with formatting under windows, and only allows one account at a time, and doesn't really handle files in a way I like.

I need at least good indentation, but points for syntax highlighting and Markdown/ReText.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [Boostnote](https://boostnote.io/) - a simple notetaking app for programmers.

#### Features

- Available on Mac, Windows & Linux.
- Write your notes using markdown
- Syntax Highlighting
- Tag your notes
- and many more

Also, check out another notetaking app called [Inkdrop](http://inkdrop.info) - a notetaking app for hackers

#### Features

- Available on Mac, Windows & Linux
- Write your notes using Github Flavoured Markdown
- Syntax Highlighting
- Sync Notes between devices
- Vim & Emacs Keybindings
- and many more

Comment: This is most definitely what I was looking for.

Comment: Had a try and noticed the files are stored in an internal json file structure, not as individual .md text file.

Comment: The  Boostnote developer plans to add support for exporting notes as markdown, html, pdf as seen [here](https://github.com/BoostIO/Boostnote/issues/52)

Comment: @NonlinearFruit I have updated by answer to reflect that.

Comment: How does Boostnote behave with when the number of notes increases to thousands? Is search fast?

Answer (score 4):

[Org-mode](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tools/index.html) is a powerful organizer with note-taking features. It is:

- Cross platform (Runs on Emacs and [other environments](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tools/index.html)). Can be easily installed on Windows and Linux
- Free and open source
- You can insert code snippets and even run them using the tags `#+BEGIN_SRC` and `#+END_SRC`
- All files are stored offline in text format, and can be easily exported into html
- Has an intuitive and easy to learn syntax, with headings, checkboxes, timestamps, and other features

You can read more about it in the [compact guide](http://orgmode.org/orgguide.pdf). Here's an example from the main website:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd give a try for OneNote. Years ago it was quite useful with this plugin.

It's freeware, it can sync all notes with OneDrive notebook (which is accessible via online, hence Linux too).

For code formatting I used years ago the [NoteHighlight plugin](http://notehighlight.codeplex.com/releases) | [(check this blog too)](http://www.codefoster.com/codeinonenote/).

**Please note:** I have not tried this since, and OneNote is version 2016 now, but binary plugins should be compatible cross-version.

Answer (score 0):

Try [medleytext.net](https://medleytext.net), it's a note taking freeware for developers.

You can insert, edit multiple syntax highlighted code blocks in real time. Really organizes your programming notes and snippets.

Should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Does it support math? Latex?